# If cell value is > 0 in any cell in range then

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that has x rows and y columns.  Each of the cells contains a number.  Usually it is 0, sometimes it is 1 or greater.

I have code that prompts me to confirm if there are any non-zero values, and then step into a snippet of code to work with those values.

I want the updated code to recognize that if even one cell has a greater than 0 value, step into a specific snippet of code.  Otherwise, ignore it.

I tried to do this with a loop, but if more than one cell has a greater than 0 value, the current code executes multiple times.

Pseudo-code that did not work:

```
For Each cell in Range("B2:C8")
    If cell.value > 0 Then
        "some code"
    End If
Next cell
```

This will execute "some code" every time a non-zero value is found, which is an issue any time more than one non-zero value occurs.

Comment: why not If sum(your range) > 0 ?

Comment: @HarassedDad see Gary's student's remark to answer posted by MarcinSzaleniec.

Comment: If there's a possibility of negative values then you need If( Sum(yourrange) <> 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to modify the code little bit like below:

```
For Each cell in Range("B2:C8")
    If cell.value > 0 Then
        "some code"
        exit for 'Now that we have executed the code once we don't need to run it again!
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: I had to move the Exit For outside of the If statement, but now it works.  Thank you

Comment: @sbagnato that will exit the for loop at first cell if you keep it outside `IF... END IF` loop!

Comment: It wont be much of a loop if you exit after the first cell.

Comment: Understood, however, it wasn't exiting with it placed inside.  Maybe I am missing something else?  I did a test with 3 cells that had non-zero values, and the "some code" executed 3 times.

Comment: @sbagnato that is strange as I don't get any such behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

I would make it shorter

```
if worksheetfunction.sum(Range("B2:C8")) > 0 then
```

Comment: I believe this would be faster than looping through the cells

Comment: This is good, especially if there are no negative value in the range

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec, and this will only run "some code" for the first instance of a non-zero value, and not for subsequent instances, correct?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood: At the first occurrence of a non-zero value, your code should "do something" and stop searching for another non-zero value. Right?
In this case, "Exit For" should solve your problem.

```
For Each cell in Range("B2:C8")
    If cell.value > 0 Then
        "some code"
        Exit For
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

I am probably late to answer this query, but just going to leave it here for future reference. My approach is to use 2 loops, for rows and columns separately. Here is a sample answer :

```
 For icol from col_start to col_end 'column loop 
        For irow from row_start to row_end 'row loop

       Og_val = Activesheet.cells(irow,icol). value

       If og_val > 0 Then 'To check if existing cell value is more than 0

        "Some code"

       End If

      Next irow
   Next icol
```